# Best way to include other CSS/JS libraries in a Github repo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, git, github

I'm wanting to include [FontAwesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome), [Bulma](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma), [jquery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery), and [jquery-ui](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui) in one of my Github repos for the frontend portion. Currently what I'm doing is using the JS file or CSS files from these projects in my own JS/CSS folders, but I feel like there is a neater way to do this. I've tried git submodules for it and they work fine, although I'm unsure if that is the best way to go about doing it.

Comment: considering using a [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network)? eg: https://code.jquery.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way is to use some dependency management system like [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm) or [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/)

Answer (score 1):

you can use a package manager like yarn , npm , bower

you can require them at your index html file 
check this 
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp
this line

```
<script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

require jquery as $

for jquery ui check this 
https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

in the document

for Font-Awesome
https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself